# Does the Game of Thrones intro change to reflect the current story?

Tags: game-of-thrones, title-sequence

In the [Game of Thrones](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/) intro, we are presented with a very steam-punk like map of interactive pieces representing the kingdoms and what they represent.

However, I noticed when Theon Greyjoy arrived in Pyke, the next episode showed Pyke on the map, rising up from the sea.  Going back a few, a friend noticed Qarth appeared as well when Daenerys and her people arrived.

Has the intro always been like this, and is it in the directors/animator's mind to always update the intro to reflect where the current events are happening?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The animators worked out four different map sequences, which can effectively indicate the locations shown in the upcoming episode. The initial plan was to show the map every time the scene changed, but this was deemed too disruptive to the storyline, and it was decided to introduce the locations in the title sequence instead.

The article can be found [here.](http://www.artofthetitle.com/2011/05/12/game-of-thrones/)

Comment: i've noticed that in season 3 they still showed a burnt winterfell on map even though there was no action happening in winterfell

Comment: @StannisBaratheon this is to show that Winterfell is still in ruins, I'm pretty sure it's tradition to show Winterfell in the opening series to show that's we'll come back to it. As we can see in the opening title of the new series, Winterfell is rebuilt but the Stark sigil is replaced with the Bolton sigil.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the intro does change to reflect the locations where the episode's story takes place, and has been doing this from the beginning of the series. For instance, when Dany finally arrives at the city of Qarth, the intro stopped showing us Vaes Dothrak (where the Dothraki horse people are from) and replaced it with Qarth.

Comment: I was pretty sick of looking at Vaes Dothrak to be honest.